# How to update standard PIP UI interface in iOS apps

Tags: ios, swift, picture-in-picture

I want to know if there's a way to customize or hide close [X] button in Standard Pip UI for ios apps. I have gone through `AVPictureInPictureController` & `AVPlayerLayer` apple documentation but I don't see any api which we can use to hide or disable close button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked on this but I guess this will do the job.
[pictureInPictureButtonStopImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avpictureinpicturecontroller/3172687-pictureinpicturebuttonstopimage)
If you can't set it to nil try to update it with clear png image :)